# How to implement User Authentication in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am new to Django.

I need to know how to implement Django Authentication in the Front end. I must to create a new App called for example "auth" and the put all the code related with Authentication?

Please give me a clue on how to structure the Authentication in the Front end.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read Chapter 14 of the Django Book

- http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14/

This is for Django 1.0, but it will help you understanding the basics.